# Book involving people turning into crystal

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book, the plot involves something along the lines of:

On an alien planet a black crystal exists which when touched turns people into crystal or stone (petrifies them). This becomes contagious so the population is rounded up into a prison camp.

They escape the camp and go and survive in the nearby hills where they find a plant which they brew in a tea and eat which is the antidote to the crystal petrification.

No idea of the author or title, but I vaguely remember the front cover being purple-ish. I remember reading it in 1998-1999, but it may have been an older book.

EDIT:

They 'mine' the material and bring it back to their planet which causes the outbreak.

People's limbs petrify and people are limping with the petrified limb.

A youngish person is the one who finds the cure by talking to someone who breaks into the camp to help people

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not a 100% match but there are some similarities to [Sentenced to Prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentenced_to_Prism).  Matches are crystal life, infective, sounds like a prison book, purple on cover, published in 1985.  Dissimilarities are the tea cure (at least I don't remember that) and the plot element of rounding people up into camps.

[image]